# Should be a groupId unique in multimodule project?

Tags: maven-2

I have a maven multimodule project. What the best practices for creating groupId? Can I use one common groupId for all modules or unique per each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no general rule. Use the `groupId` to separate (or not) things that have different concerns, but *coarse grained*. [XWiki](http://svn.xwiki.org/svnroot/xwiki/) is a good illustration of this approach. Hibernate is another example, they use the same `groupId` for all their modules.

But **nothing** forces you to use a unique `groupId` per module, this seems clearly too *fine grained* to me (this sounds like creating a package for each class).

In a corporate environment, using something like `a.b.appname` and then `a.b.appname.moduleN` if the application is big and has many modules is a common pattern.